# How to I get the controller_name of a subclassed controller from its parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using some namespaced controllers that also inherit from a parent controller. In each subclass I need to have ([for anyone wondering why...](http://bjhess.com/blog/when_single_table_inheritance_attacks/)):

```
class Fruits::ApplesController < FruitsController
  # controller_name below is 'apples'
  require_dependency "fruits/#{controller_name}"
  ...
end
```

So, since I'd rather have the require_dependency line once in my parent class I tried to move it to FruitsController, but the problem is that controller_name is now equal to "fruits"..

```
class FruitsController < ApplicationController
  # controller_name is 'fruits' no matter which subclassed controller is called
  require_dependency "fruits/#{controller_name}"
  ...
end
```

So how can I properly get the value of the subclassed controller name in FruitsController, so that I can keep that require_dependency line out of my subclasses? controller_path doesn't help either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above in my response to @ElliotNelson (thanks a lot btw!), here's the code that I've placed in my `FruitsController` that has allowed me to re-factor my original code:

```
def self.inherited(subclass)    
  subclass.require_dependency subclass.controller_name
  super
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As written, your "require_dependency" statement is only executed once, when the parent loads.

You could potentially use the Class#inherited method to require your dependency, like this (code untested).

```
class FruitsController < ApplicationController
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.require_dependency subclass.to_s.underscore
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I had to add a call to `super` at the end for it to work, and I've opted to use `subclass.controller_name` instead of `subclass.to_s.underscore` because it returns what I need (already underscored and no _controller on the end, so it matches the model name). I'll post the working code below...

Answer (score 0):

The require statement above in the `Fruits` class is executed only once during the loading of the parent class, which means subclasses won't have it executed again. Check the following example:

```
class A
  puts name
end

class B < A
end
#=> A
```

So, you have to execute a separate require per subclass and thus you can't refactor it that way you want.